# A critical point of a system of ODE: neither linearly stable nor linearly unstable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, terminology, stability-in-odes

Suppose $\dot{x}(t) = f(x(t))$
and let $x^*$ be a critical point, i.e., $f(x^*) = 0$. 
Let us consider the linearization of $f$ at $x^*$. Thus, we have $\dot{x}(t) = A(x^*)x(t)$.
Suppose the eigenvalues of $A^*=A(x^*)$ are always non-positive (i.e., always less than or equals to $0$).

If all eigenvalues of $A^*$ are negative, we say $x^*$ is linearly stable.
Suppose $A^*$ has zero eigenvalues. Then, what can we say about the linear stability of $x^*$?

**Is there any name referring to such a case?** It seems that the notion of [marginal stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_stability) is suitable.
I think it is appropriate calling such a $x^*$ as **linearly marginally stable**.
However, I couldn't find precise references that use such terminology.

The rests are the collections of what I have searched:

Wikipedia page of [linear stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_stability) says

> If there exists an eigenvalue with zero real part then the question about stability cannot be solved on the basis of the first approximation.

It seems that the notion of [the center manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_manifold) is the most relevant notion, however, it simply refers to the eigenspace of $A(x^*)$ that corresponds to $\lambda = 0$, and does not itself tell the (linear) stability of $x^*$.

Any suggestions/comments/answers will be very appreciated.

Comment: This is called a critical case. See, for example, https://books.google.com/books?id=u1O8AAAAIAAJ&lpg=PA1&pg=PA1#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @AVK Thank you so much. It is really helpful. I tried to access the book you mentioned, however, it is really hard to find one. It would be really appreciated if you could provide another reference. Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-50085-5_10